# Copying data folder from Elasticsearch 1.x to 2.y

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, data-migration

Is it safe to migrate data from Elasticsearch 1.5 to empty 2.4.0 by simply copying data folder?

We tried:
1. Install fresh Elasticsearch 2.4.0
2. Stop Elasticsearch 1.5
3. Copy data folder from 1.5 to 2.4.0
4. Starting Elasticsearch 2.4.0

It worked well, Elasticsearch 2.0 picked up all the indices, but I do not see any description of this approach in documentation, thus I am not sure if it is safe.
Is it acceptable way of migration, or should I use some migration tools as recommended? I am not interested in not having down-time, just need to migrate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes.

As mentioned on the [Upgrade Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) page:

> Elasticsearch can read indices created in the previous major version. Older indices must be reindexed or deleted.

Then they go on to give some specific examples, which doesn't include 1.x to 2.x anymore, but the concept is the same.

> Elasticsearch 6.x can use indices created in Elasticsearch 5.x, but not those created in Elasticsearch 2.x or before. Elasticsearch 5.x can use indices created in Elasticsearch 2.x, but not those created in 1.x or before.

**Important note**: in my experience, if possible, it's more performant to re-create the index completely in the new Elasticsearch version. However, using an index created in an older version temporarily to help with a migration is totally fine.